# Difference between infinite union and arbitrary union of closed/open sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, set-theory

I am trying to understand the following idea from a first course in real analysis about the topology of open and closed sets in a metric space $(X, d)$.

Take a set $K_n$ = $\left[-1 + \dfrac{1}{n}, 1 - \dfrac{1}{n}\right]$.

For $n=1$ we have [0].

for $n=2$ we have $\left[\dfrac{-1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{2}\right]$,

for $n=3$ we have $\left[\dfrac{-2}{3}, \dfrac{2}{3}\right]$,

with each of the above sets being closed.

However, for $\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}$ we have [0], which is open because any ball of radius $r>0$ will include other points not equal to 0, so the ball is not contained in the set [0], so the infinite intersection is open.

But then we have the theorem that says if $A_{\gamma}$ is closed, $\bigcap\limits_{\gamma \in I}A_{\gamma}$ is closed.

Maybe I am misunderstanding the difference between "arbitrary intersection of an infinite family" and "infinite intersection of indexed sets," but if I have the intersection of all the $\gamma \in I$, and I is an infinite set such as $\mathbb{N}$, with $A_{\gamma}$ defined as $[-1 + 1/{\gamma}, 1 - 1/{\gamma}]$, is this not the exact same thing as we had before, i.e.,

$\bigcap\limits_{\gamma}A_{\gamma}$ we have [0], which is open.

Hopefully my language and notation are correct.

You can also find a similar contradiction with the infinite intersection:

$K_n$ = $[-1 + 1/n, 1 - 1/n]$.

For $n=1$ we have [0].

for $n=2$ we have [-1/2, 1/2],

for $n=3$ we have [-2/3, 2/3],

but for $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}$ we have $(1,1)$, which is open.

But then there is a theorem that says if $A_{\gamma}$ is  closed, $\bigcup\limits_{\gamma \in I}A_{\gamma}$ is closed.

Any explanation or guidance on how I can understand where I am having trouble would be appreciated.

Comment: $[0]=\{0\}$ is very much not an open space, as it does not contain any open ball. Or maybe you mean something else by that. I assume you mean $[0]=[0,0]$.

Comment: By the way, what theorem says that an infinite union of closed sets is closed?

Comment: Your paragraph starting *However, for...* would have been a perfect demonstration of the fact that $[0]$ is ***not*** open, if only you had written the words "*not open*" in place of the word "*open*".

Comment: This is Thoerem 2.24 from baby Rudin.  As to other comment, my understanding is that a set containing a single point like {0}, which above is written [0], is not closed in a metric space because any open ball of radius r>0 will contain other real numbers and so the ball is not a subset of the point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to write less in the comments, in a place where it is easier to edit, I'll write some facts here.

- In any metric space $(X,d)$, a singleton $\{ x\}$ is closed. It is usually not an open set. If it is open, then there exists $r>0$ such that $\{ y\in X: d(x,y)<r \}=\{0\}$.
- An infinite union of closed sets is usually not open. It is true that a general union of open sets is open. If I am looking at the correct version of the theorem you are referring to, then you are misquoting it.
- An open subset may also be closed if the space is not connected. While $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, you do not seem to rely on it explicitly for your "contradiction". So I think it is possible that you assume closed set are not open and that open sets are not closed.

Comment: I got the notation and definitions mixed up. Thank you for replying. Upon reading your reply and re-reading the section of the book, I see now. If I take arbitrarily many open sets, the union is open. And for arbitrarily many closed sets, the intersection is closed. From above, yes, the singleton set is closed. Not sure what I was thinking. Finally, for arbitrarily many closed sets, the union is not necessarily closed.